# EVI coefficient values for Sentinel 2 image analysis

Tags: remote-sensing, sentinel-2, evi

I am estimating EVI for Sentinel imagery and wanted to know the values of the coefficients L, C1, C2 etc.

All the literature I have found use values from MODIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my quick search on available articles, there appears to be no published article covering this topic, as such, it looks like you have stumbled upon a topic that could be a reasonable article - the derivation of constants for calculating EVI from Sentinel-2 imagery.

If that is too big a task for you at this stage, I'd suggest relying on other vegetation indices, or just going with the flow, and use the constants from MODIS (while obviously noting that the constants are taken from MODIS, and haven't been properly validated for use with S2 data).

Comment: Lydholm- Thank your for your answer. At present, I do not have the capacity to generate the constants. But I will try some analysis using the values from MODIS EVI.